# Convert SQL Binary Data to String in C#

Tags: c#

Does anybody have sample code to convert from binary data to string in c#?

Comment: Take note here, if your data is binary because it is encrypted, you must decrypt it before you can read it's data.

Comment: With binary data, you mean a byte array (byte[])?

Comment: What are you trying to accommplish?  We could go about this any many ways and most will be the wrong way if we don't have more information about what you are trying to accomplish and what is in the binary data.  We could decode it by parsing the data, or we could encode it in base64, or decode it to unicode.  What does the binary data represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you just need to decode the binary data. Therefore you need an encoding (like utf-8 or unicode).

Example:

```
var textFromBinary = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myBinaryData);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your binary data is stored in `byte` array and you want to convert it to Base64-encoding, you can use [`Convert.ToBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx) method:

```
var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(yourBinaryDataHere);
```

Answer (score 0):

In modern versions of `.NET`, we can simply use the `.ToString()` override of `BinaryData` for a `UTF-8` decoding of the contained bytes.

```
string data = myBinaryData.ToString()
```